# Open new popup window without address bars in firefox & IE

Tags: firefox, address-bar

hope someone can help. just cannot get a new window to open in Firefox  without  address bars. IE works fine with below code

```
window.open('/pageaddress.html', 'winname', 
  directories=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0,location=0,status=0,     
    menubar=0,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,
      width=400,height=350);
```

I need to make for all browser

Comment: In modern Firefox such folly does not work.

Comment: Firefox 3 note
In Firefox 3, dom.disable_window_open_feature.location now defaults to true, forcing the presence of the Location Bar much like in IE7. See bug 337344 for more information.

So below firefox 3 only hiding of the location bar works.

Comment: This doesn't work either in MS Edge ... All these parameters and other window features are just ignored.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Firefox 3.0 and higher have disabled setting `location` by default. `resizable` and `status` are also disabled by default. You can verify this by typing `about:config' in your address bar and filtering by "dom". The items of interest are:

- dom.disable_window_open_feature.location
- dom.disable_window_open_feature.resizable
- dom.disable_window_open_feature.status

You can get further information at the [Mozilla Developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open) site. What this basically means, though, is that you won't be able to do what you want to do.

One thing you might want to do (though it won't solve your problem), is put quotes around your window feature parameters, like so:

```
window.open('/pageaddress.html','winname','directories=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=400,height=350');
```

Comment: thanks for your answer 
As you said it is disabled by firefox

Comment: @Intelekshual   Title bar not hidden. Checked in IE,FF,Chrome and Opera

Comment: Could you have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25703925/how-to-open-tel48123-link-client-side-without-openning-new-window-tab-in-bro

Answer (score 20):

I agree we can not hide address bar in modern browsers, but we can hide the URL in address bar (e.g show URL `about:blank`). The following is my work around solution:

```
var iframe = '<html><head><style>body, html {width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0}</style></head><body><iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com" style="height:calc(100% - 4px);width:calc(100% - 4px)"></iframe></body></html>';

var win = window.open("","","width=600,height=480,toolbar=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes");
win.document.write(iframe);
```

Comment: worked beautifully for print without url! dont know if this is good for the asked question tho!

Answer (score 18):

Check the [mozilla documentation on window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/API/Window/open).
The window features ("directory=...,...,height=350") etc. arguments should be a string:

```
window.open('/pageaddress.html','winname',"directories=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0,location=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=400,height=350");
```

Try if that works in your browsers. Note that some of the features might be overridden by user preferences, such as "location" (see doc.)

Comment: Title bar not hidden.  Checked in IE,FF,Chrome and Opera

Comment: location bar not hidden

Comment: Not only I checked **https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/API/Window/open** but I also tested the window features: using `windowFeatures = 
 "menubar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes"`  or `windowFeatures = "menubar=no,location=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,status=no"` makes absolutely no difference, i.e. the result is exactly the same.

Answer (score 12):

Workaround - Open a modal popup window and embed the external URL as an iframe.

Answer (score 3):

In internet explorer, if the new url is from the same domain as the current url, the window will be open without an address bar.  Otherwise, it will cause an address bar to appear.  One workaround is to open a page from the same domain and then redirect from that page.

Answer (score 0):

check this if it works it works fine for me

```js
var windowObjectReference;
var strWindowFeatures = "menubar=no,location=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,status=yes,width=400,height=350";

function openRequestedPopup() {
  windowObjectReference = window.open("http://www.flyingedge.in/", "CNN_WindowName", strWindowFeatures);
}

openRequestedPopup();
```

Comment: No, this does not work, at least not in current Firefox. Menubar and srollbars are disabled, but the address bar still appears, and the window is still resizable.