# Open window without toolbars

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to open new window without toolbars using the code below but it opens new window with the toolbars (at least in IE). Any idea what am I doing wrong?

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="popupWindow(this.href)" target="_blank"><img src="/myImage"/><a>

function popupWindow(url)
{
    window.open(url,"MyWindow","config='toolbar=no, menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no'");
}
```

Comment: Does it matter that you spelled the "status" option at the end wrong?

Comment: Also, what do you expect the "toolbars" to mean? Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open to get all options.

Comment: The third param is just a comma-separated list of key=val pairs, not an assignment string. Remove the config='' portion of it.

Answer (score 8):

A quick Google search found the syntax for this at [DevShed](http://forums.devshed.com/html-programming-1/opening-new-window-without-toolbar-scrollbar-etc-313.html):

```
<script language="javascript">
function myPopup(url, windowname, w, h, x, y)
{
    window.open(url, windowname, "resizable=no, toolbar=no, scrollbars=no, menubar=no, status=no, directories=no, width=" + w + ", height=" + h + ", left=" + x + ", top=" + y);
}
</script>
```

Note that it differs from your own in that you have `config=` as part of the last argument, and it's not needed (as AlienWebguy pointed out).

Answer (score 3):

There were several issues in your code:

- There should be only 3 ws in `wwww.google.com`
- Unnecessary `config='`.  Also remove that final closing `'`.
- `atus=no` should be `status=no`

Correcting these issues makes the pop-up work:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="popupWindow(this.href)" target="_blank">Click</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
function popupWindow(url)
  {
    window.open(url,"MyWindow","toolbar=no, menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I've corrected all this but still getting the address bar etc when the window opens.

Comment: Does your browser allow these changes?  For example, FF disables this by default - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909645/open-new-popup-window-without-address-bars-in-firefox-ie.

Comment: The code I'm writing is for the company's intranet, which officially only supports IE therefore I only test it with this browser (IE8)

Comment: I think I've got something. The real URL I'm transferring to the JS function looks something like this: /irj/portal?NavigationTarget=ROLES://pcd:portal_content/hello and I'm getting "Invalid argument" in the javascript console. Perhaps I need to escape special characters in this URL?

Comment: I tried with escape(), encodeURI() and encodeURIComponent() but still getting the error above. Any ideas.....?

Comment: If you get the right result when passing http://www.google.com, but the wrong result when you're using the real URL, then it's the URL causing the problem.

Comment: Solved it and its not the URL, for some reason in IE the name of the window has to be an empty string. So, if I rename "MyWindow" to "" it works. Strange but googling shows more people have this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to everyone for replying.

The issues mentioned were typos here, they were correct on my original code.

For some reason in IE the name of the window has to be an empty string. So, if I rename "MyWindow" to "" it works. Strange but googling shows more people have this problem.