# How to hide/disappear address bar using javascript window.open method?

Tags: javascript

I have a page including a link which I want to open it in a new window and it's working just fine the only thing is that the address bar is still appearing while I have set the value 'location=no' below is the code in which I am working...

```
function openWindow() {

    window.open('somepage.html',abc,'scrollbars=yes,width=600px,height=450px,location=no');

}
```

Comment: I believe some browsers simply don't allow you to hide the address bar even on windows opened from JS - certainly you can't rely on it working. (Which browser are you testing with?)

Comment: Check this out [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909645/open-new-popup-window-without-address-bars-in-firefox-ie](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909645/open-new-popup-window-without-address-bars-in-firefox-ie)

Comment: @Stanley - Was just about to post the same link ;)

Comment: But its working for me. What browser are you using Umair?

Comment: Almighty google tells you to go to this place: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open it's called a documentation.