# JavaScript browser navbar event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to prevent users to navigate to URL´s that are not accessed through html element. Example:

Actually navigating on: `myweb.com/news`

And I want to navigate to `myweb.com/news?article_id=10` by writing this in the browser navigation bar to avoid pressing any element (like `<a>`).

When the user writes `myweb.com/news?article_id=10` in the browser url, at the moment he presses enter, the browser should not allow him to navigate to the url.

**I have tried:**

```
//This wont work since jquery does not support it
$(window.location.href).on('change', function() {
    //Here check if href contains '?'
    alert("Not allowed");
});

//Neither works, doesnt do anything
$(window).on('change', function() {
    alert("Not allowed");
});
```

**References:**
there is something similar asked here [On - window.location.hash - Change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680785/on-window-location-hash-change), but im interested in the 'parameter' version of that question.

Comment: Maybe a related [article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351273/how-to-disable-the-url-address-bar-using-javascript-or-jquery)

Comment: I'm not sure that you can actually do that. For sure you can use the history API, listen for changes and if there is something forbidden then change the path immediately.

Comment: User should be allowed to navigate anywhere he wants from the navbar. Instead just redirect the user to `/news` despite any entered parameters

Answer (score 2):

There are some known solutions :

- ) Each time a user click a link - you save the page value to a cookie.
  Later , at the server- you check that interval ( value-1 ... value+1).
- ) You can also save to a hidden field and check that value in the server.

So let's say a user is on page 3. ( the server serve that page - so a cookie/hidden value with value 3 is exists)

now he tries to go to page 10 :

you  - in the server side - reads the cookie + requested Page number. if the interval is bigger than 1 - then you deny that request.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an event listener:

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event)
{
    var location = document.location;
    var state =  JSON.stringify(event.state);
});
```

To check the URL, The best thing would be to match it against a regex like:

```
if (url.match(/\?./)) {
  // do not allow access
}
```

You might need to extend this, depending on other URL's that you need to forbid access to.