# Run HTML page in Windows window like exe

Tags: javascript, html, windows, browser, exe

I have an HTML quiz (it is designed in html+css, but calculated and animated in JavaScript). Therefore, it opens in browser by default (quiz.html). I want to make it open in for example Windows window or something different. Is it possible. Or some portable browser, and set up HTML file to open by it. How?

The problem is that browser environment (bookmarks, forward, refresh buttons) is visible, and I don't want that. I want it to open in its specific environment, because it will be placed on 20 computers with different browsers etc... I can install anything on those machines. Or is it maybe possible to set up my quiz.html file to open in some other unpopular browser with no so many buttons and details?

Comment: You might open your quiz in a popup (you depend on a basic page and browser though) and remove all the feature you don't want, like buttons, address bar, etc... check this:http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like said in comment, you might try to open your page in a pop.

```
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_open
```

With the following code, I manage to get a popup without anything but the page and the address bar (on [Firefox Potable](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable)).

`window.open("http://www.w3schools.com","width=200,height=100",'directories=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no');`

You would still have the adress bar in Firefox, but this can be remove following this post:
[Open new popup window without address bars in firefox & IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909645/open-new-popup-window-without-address-bars-in-firefox-ie)

Comment: This can work. But, can I set up somehow to open my html file and the first page have thse configurations you send me. You know, to have a shortcut on a desktop, and when I click on an icon, it opens in browser with no taskbar, address bar...

Comment: Is there an option, to have a shortcut on desktop if my html file (quiz.html) and set up somehow to open in chrome, everytime, either my default browser is Firefox. When I use properties/general/ and change the defuault programs to open with - it applies to all html files.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I don't think this is possible. Like you said, those settings are general. You might try to create a new extension (let's say "htl") that has no program that is related to. Then, since this is un unknown extension, you will have the possibility to select a program to be associated to this extension. Select chrone chrome, and this all the time to open such extension. This might work!

Comment: Be carefull when selecting the extension, be sure this might not be later in the time be a real program extension.

Comment: This with extension change is great idea and it really works. Thanks for saving my time.

Answer (score 0):

If restricting your users to IE is ok then you want an [HTML Application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application) (*.HTA) which allows the hosting of HTML/Script in a standalone non-browser window which would seem to be ideal for your purposes.

[MSDN ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250409%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).