# BrowserWindowOpener component - Vaadin

Tags: java, javascript, vaadin

how can I get the same behaviour like BrwoserWindowOpener do ? 
Exacly: open the external file in new browser window with disable for changing URL bar?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable changing the URL you have to set the **location** feature to 0:

```
BrowserWindowOpener browserWindowOpener = new BrowserWindowOpener(new ExternalResource("http://google.com"));
browserWindowOpener.setFeatures("location=0");
```

**NOTE:** firefox by default opens up popup windows with location=0 (see [Open new popup window without address bars in firefox & IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909645/open-new-popup-window-without-address-bars-in-firefox-ie)), but if you try with Chrome for example, you'll see that you can edit the address by default.