# To hide the address bar in popup window by setting disable_window_feature.location value to false

Tags: javascript, window.open

I need to Hide address bar in Pop up window(Security reasons). i used

`window.open(“res.html”,“mywindow”,location=0,menubar=0,status=0,scrollbars=0,width=100,height100″);`

in my JavaScript Which is working fine. But, for mozilla we need to set **Dom.disable_window_open_feature.location** value.

In Web application how can i set this in users firfox browser? Is there any way to set this using java script. I want setDom.disable_window_open_feature.location value using JavaScript before i use window.open. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't hide it, and even if you could, this would almost certainly provide no security for your application as it could be simply overridden.

The reason any up to date browser will not allow you to hide the address bar, is actually for security/[anti-phishing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phishing) reasons itself. If the address bar was hidden, and you included a popup window (for example to a bank's customer page), and you made a site that looked like the banks login page to capture their customers details. Since the address bar is forced to always be shown, the end user would instantly see the domain was not from their bank.

If you give some more information as to why you have a security requirement to hide the address bar, maybe we can provide an alternative method to help you.

[Intelekshual](https://stackoverflow.com/users/127769/intelekshual) gives a good explanation in the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909645/open-new-popup-window-without-address-bars-in-firefox-ie), but note this will only work for your local machine, and not other web users:

> Firefox 3.0 and higher have disabled setting location by default.
> resizable and status are also disabled by default. You can verify this
> by typing `about:config' in your address bar and filtering by "dom".
> The items of interest are:
>
> - dom.disable_window_open_feature.location
> - dom.disable_window_open_feature.resizable
> - dom.disable_window_open_feature.status

Also have a look at the Mozilla documentation for [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open) to get the official information.

> In Firefox 3, dom.disable_window_open_feature.location now defaults to
> true, forcing the presence of the Location Bar much like in IE7. See
> bug [337344](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=337344) for more information.