# How to open `tel:+48123` link client side without openning new window/tab in browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, browser, hyperlink

I need to deliver the same behaviour if I clicked `tel:+4842566` link by myself. The default telephony application should call the number nothing more.

I managed that besides that new tab opens. I wrote:

```
function Call(){
    window.open("tel:+4842566",'_blank');     
}
```

and this:

```
function Call(){
    window.open("tel:+4842566");     
}
```

and this:

```
  function Call(){
        document.getElementById('mymailto').click();
    }


<a href="tel:+48123456" id="mymailto" style="display:none"></a>
```

Results are the same. Computer calls the number but new tab is openned.

**Question:** Is it possible to invoke/open this link without new tab/window?

**EDIT:** Before I tried to run this client side I did it on server side but did not realise that when I deploy application it is not the client who will be calling:

```
public ActionResult Call(int id, string number) {
  System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    string formattedNumber = "tel:+48" + formatPhoneNumber(number);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("NUMBER " + formattedNumber);
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = formattedNumber;
    proc.Start();
    Person person = db.Persons.Find(id);
    return RedirectToAction("Edit", new Person { Id = id });
}
```

but then I didn't get new tab, maybe it will help somehow.

**EDIT 2:**
I don't simply look for href link cause launching `tel:` link is only one of 2 things that happen at the same time:

```
<p>@Html.ActionLink("Call Cell Phone", "Call", new { id = Model.Id, number = Model.CellNumber }, new { @class = "btn btn-default", onclick = "Call();" })</p>
```

I go to the controller action and invoke `Call()` javascript method and JavaScript method is the only place that simple openning any link can be done.

Comment: I'm no security expert but my instinct suggests that allowing web pages to programmatically cause my device to make a phone call would comprise some sort of security issue.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstamd your question, but are you not looking for this? Simple html `<a href="tel:+123456">call now </a>`

Comment: @Pointy Thank you for suggest. The application will be used only by  authorized users whose devices(PC->Windows,Tablets->Android) I will configure by myself. Maybe there is a way to start a process on their side by JavaScript like I showed in the edit to OP.

Comment: Well my phone anyway won't actually start dialing until I confirm. I tried using a hidden `<iframe>` but that didn't work.

Comment: @Pointy The PC is the most important, I don't want this tab to be openned. Skype comes to front anyway.

Comment: change "window.open" to "location.href=", and remove the parens if you want. you can also keep a hidden iframe with an about:blank src on the page, and set its src to the tel: uri at any time to trigger the same behavior.

Comment: @Pointy I posted the answer it may interest you.

Comment: @dandavis Could you please elaborate on this hidden iframe and how place result of `location.href="+481234"` in this hidden frame, I am still newbie at Java Script and HTML. I posted solution but it only works for Chrome but in work I want to use IE.

Comment: <iframe src=about:blank id=fr1></iframe> ... document.frames[0].src="tel:+4842566";

Answer (score 11):

The solution is much easier:

```
document.location.href="tel:"+the_number;
```

Comment: Yes, this works. But you should use an equal sign to make an asignment :)
`document.location.href = 'tel:0123...'`

Answer (score 4):

Ok. This is little cheat and it works on Chrome, but does not work on IE, which I use in development of ASP .NET MVC Web Apllications.

```
   function Call(){
        document.getElementById('mymailto').click();
    }
```

and in HTML

```
<a href="tel:+48123456" id="mymailto" style="display:none"></a>
```

Answer (score 3):

window.open("tel:888", "_self");

Second argument is same to "target" attribute of 'a' tag.
Here is an explanation what's target:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp
So "_self" means current frame (=current page in most cases)

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this is:

```
var call_app = window.open("tel:"+$(this).text(), "_blank");
call_app.close();
```