# How to hide address bar on new window using javascript?

Tags: javascript, browser, address-bar

I have this code :

```
  <a href="/upload/photo/" onclick="window.open(this.href, 'windowName', 'width=500, height=200, left=200, top=200, location=0'); return false;">
```

How to modify it so that it opens new window without address bar (in all browsers)?

Comment: Asked and answered. Try google [Open new popup window without address bars in firefox & IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909645/open-new-popup-window-without-address-bars-in-firefox-ie)

Comment: @CollinDriscoll Thanks for the hint. So is there other 'thing' which can do the same without address bar?

Comment: You can craft a faux popup inside the current window using (for example) a modal iframe, but no there is no way in current browsers to create a popup without an address bar consistently.