# How hide child window address bar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Window.open function for the open child window I want to hide address bar from child window, can you tell me how can I hide the child window address bar. I have mentioned below function that I am using.

```
    window.open("http://www.google.com", "Title", 'toolbar=0,addressbar=no,menubar=no,location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no');
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909645/open-new-popup-window-without-address-bars-in-firefox-ie

Comment: can you tell me which one i need to use its not work for me

Answer (score 0):

According to the post to which you have been directed this is not possible (for security reasons).

If it is critical not to have the address bar you could try opening your target url in an iframe, put the iframe in a div and show that as a pop-up (i.e. show the div as some kind of a modal with CSS).