# Is it possible to hide the url of window.open whilst showing a html file in chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

does anyone have any idea on how this was achieved?

On this site there is a big sign in button which redirected to a log in page in a new chrome window with a blank url bar, I inspected the button and onclick it ran the function login(), I looked everywhere in the code for a function called login, I could not find it anywhere, my question was does anyone know what the function could of been? I researched everywhere and everybody is saying it is not possible to hide the url bar of a website anymore, however this proves otherwise, does anyone know how this was achieved. I know it is definitely possible to hide the url, however I thought you could not open a file when using

```
window.open('','_blank',
```

edit - This is chrome, not ie or firefox, and that was 7 years ago

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open new popup window without address bars in firefox & IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909645/open-new-popup-window-without-address-bars-in-firefox-ie)

Comment: That was 7 years ago, and this is chrome..

Comment: `about:blank` is the url bar. This is the normal window layout for sized popup in chrome, you can create one yourself with `window.open('','_blank', 'width=500;height=500')` (call it in a click event to avoid being blocked) https://jsfiddle.net/gjkkd2fo/

Comment: @Kaiido right, but can you do the same with a whole html page? like in the picture above?

Comment: Yes I can do it. My example is a whole html page. You can build it from the main page with whatever complex page tou'd like.

Comment: How would you do that? Would you just insert the whole website html inside the popup.document.body.innerHTML?