# How to view HTML webpage in a new window?

Tags: html

folks! I have made a HTML file for example index.html and I wanted it in a new window or with a own GUI window not the browser. A new window with no borders should display the html webpage. It should also support HTML, Javascript and CSS.

Comment: Do you want to create an [Electron](https://electron.atom.io/) app?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by 'own GUI window not the browser'.  Is this a webpage?  An android app?  An iphone app?  A windows/mac/linux desktop app?

Maybe check this answer if you're just trying to launch a new popup window from the browser without all the toolbars etc:
[Open new popup window without address bars in firefox & IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909645/open-new-popup-window-without-address-bars-in-firefox-ie)

If that's not what you're trying to do then you will need to be way more specific.

Comment: The link you have given is correct but can you please send a link for chrome. Thank you so much!