# I want to create a website without menu bar and address bar

Tags: javascript, php, html, internet-explorer, web

I have a website that we usually push a script using sccm to open up a website at a specific time, but I don't want the web address to be visible to users, so I always deploy the website in kiosk mode.

I want to know if I can create or change the website look by removing the menu bar and address bar, we can push the link alone and not without the kiosk mode.

I have written the code and it is with a batch file that is pushed to the users system on the corporate network and it launches but only in kiosk mode and it covers the whole screen of the user, which is what I want to avoid.

Comment: Nope. If it existed, that would be a browser feature not a website feature. Doing so would be a terrible security risk though - taking away from users the ability to see what website they are on sounds very shady. If you have security concerns or want to limit access, then you should simply implement some kind of authentication system on your website to restrict access.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open new popup window without address bars in firefox & IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909645/open-new-popup-window-without-address-bars-in-firefox-ie)

Comment: Hello Jared,  I want the website to seem like a desktop app and not because it's shady

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your response. I got to achieve this by creating a script that will start chrome.exe and open the url in --app mode. this works fine for all users that have google chrome

Answer (score 1):

use [php Desktop](https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop)

you will be able to make your website a desktop app without menu bar or address bar, also you can set window default size

Comment: Hello and Thanks for your feedback,i tried this but the generated executable file after installation didnt load the page, i dont know if there is a way to load the webapplication folders/files and also maybe set the url to load

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this by using Javascript or by using IE option or setting then it is not possible.

There are security related reasons why any developer should not hide the address bar.

User should know that which site he is accessing and on which site he is providing any information.

I am not sure whether PHP provides any way to achieve it but it is not recommended.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I got to achieve this by creating a script that will start chrome.exe and open the url in --app mode. this works fine for all users that have google chrome.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know about your solution. I suggest you to post your solution as an answer and try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.